# Caratheodory's theorem original proof

Tags: geometry, soft-question, math-history, convex-geometry, convex-hulls

I saw that Carathéodory's theorem was proved for the first time in [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01449883). My German is very poor and the paper seems to be about power series. My question is in which part of the paper does Carathéodory prove his theorem.